# What it's wrong with this if-else?

Tags: android, camera

I'm creating an app for make the flash camera blink, but I have a problem with switching off the method. These are my variables:

```
Camera camera = null;
Parameters parameters;
int delay = 600;
int period = 600;
int delay1 = 300;
int period1 = 600;
Timer timer, timer2;
```

This method I'm using to make the flash camera blink:

```
timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cameraOn();
            }
    },delay1,period1);

    timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cameraOff();
            }
    },delay,period);
```

And now is when the problem comes, there's a button to switch off all this, but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it switches off perfect, sometimes it goes back to the previous activity like I want, but the flash camera stays switched on. What is wrong? Here are the methods to switch on-off the camera flash:

```
private void cameraOff() {
     parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
     camera.setParameters(parameters);
     camera.release();
     camera = null;
}

private void cameraOn() {
     camera = Camera.open();
     parameters = camera.getParameters();
     parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
     camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

And here is the button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer2.cancel();
    if(camera != null){
        cameraOff();
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application (as provided) is never going to work, due to a design flaw:

In the `cameraOff()` method you set `camera` to `null`. This method is triggered at a fixed interval, so next time the method is called again you have a `NullPointerException` as `camera` was set to `null`...

I do not know why you feel the urge to set it to `null`, but you need to do so elsewhere, or add checks whether `camera` is `null` or not.

Furthermore (to probable cause of your problem), the `TimerTasks` are executed on a different thread. When you cancel your timers, the value of `camera` is unknown and it might be possible that `cameraOff()` is called twice. Once from the `TimerTask` thread (as it was about to execute) and once from your main thread (because `camera` was not yet set so `null`).

Again, I wonder why you need to set `camera` to `null`, as this seems to cause most of your problems.

Comment: But I need to set camera to null for the if, because if I dont leave the camera in null how I check later in if?

Comment: Set a (`boolean`) value somewhere storing the state of the camera?